# How would I use a foreach loop to calculate the nearest distance using latitude on longitude

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, distance, spatial

I am trying to calculate the nearest distance to a user using mySQL latitude and longitude data.

My goal is to get the users latitude and longitude, query the database and select all of the locations and run the distance formula against the users location and all of the locations in my database. Im having trouble with the code as I am still a little confused about the foreach concept. Would anyone be able to help me out :)?

Comment: In what coordinate system do you store coordinates in DB?

Comment: floats of size (10,6)

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

Spatial functions were added to MySQL in version 5.7. If you are storing the latitude and longitude in your database, say in table `locations`, you can use, for example, [function `st_distance_sphere()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/spatial-convenience-functions.html#function_st-distance-sphere) to compute the distance between some fixed position and each location:

```
select l.*, 
    st_distance_sphere(
        point(latitude, longitude), 
        point(:latitude, :longitude)
    ) as distance_in_meters
from locations l
```

`:latitute` and `:longitude` represents the parameters to the query (the position of the user).

Notes:

- Don't loop! SQL is a set-based language, that provides a whole set of tools that make it easy to process datasets without such iterative constructs
- I would recommend storing your spatial data as [spatial objects](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/spatial-types.html) rather than as latitude/longitude; this will greatly improve the performance of your queries as your data gets bigger

Comment: I see, and just to make sure I understand,

Comment: you're selecting all from the locations table? Using "SELECT l.*,

Comment: then using st_distance_sphere to test all of the latitude and longitudes in the locations table against one location, correct?

Comment: @NicoleHolloway: yes, this selects all columns and rows of the table, with an additional column, called `distance_in_meters`, that gives the distance between each location and the user's positions.

Comment: and then to find the nearest location, how would I go about that? thank you for being patient with me, as im still relatively new to programing :)!

Comment: @NicoleHolloway: just add an `order by` clause at the end of the query, like so: `order by distance_in_meters limit 1`

Comment: Last question ..  What do you think would be the best way for me to formulate the table? :)

Comment: @NicoleHolloway: this is (shortly) discussed in the question. I would recommend storing your spatial data as `point`s, along with other relevant information about the location (`name`, `id`, and so on).

Comment: It's discussed in the *answer*